# Trying to Access Javascript from embedded page

Tags: javascript, grooveshark

According to the APIs I should be able to skip grooveshark using the following...

```
window.Grooveshark.next()
```

However, I get that Grooveshark is undefined... Could this have something to do with me embedding it?

```
<object id="groovy" type="text/html" data="http://grooveshark.com/" style="width:100%; height:400px; margin:1%;">
</object>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> You can use a bookmarklet or extension/addon to inject JS into the page and use the methods available.

It looks like you are trying to access the API through JS in a page that embeds `http://grooveshark.com/`. This won't work.

You would need to access the `window` object of the embedded page, not the outer page. There are methods for communicating across frames, but since the page is on a different domain, you run into [security restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You *cannot* access the API when it is embedded in a regular webpage. You have to use an extension (which has different security privileges) or a bookmarklet (which executes in the context of the page the user is viewing).